# Несколько модальных окон на странице

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 72px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  /* background-color: #fefefe; */
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  /* border: 1px solid #888; */
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
  to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
  to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  margin-top: -11px;
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-body {
  padding: 20px 16px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 203px;
  color: #7f819a;
  margin-left: 3px;
  background:#eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Вот код модального окна, таких на странице должно быть несколько, у каждого разный ID.

Я конечно могу просто накопировать код и поменять значения переменных, но как это сделать не костыльно?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. На странице подключается jQuery. Если есть возможность воспользоваться им - делаем это, иначе читаем дальше =)
2. Кнопки приводим к виду `<button class="myBtn"
   data-modal="myModal1">Open Modal</button>`
3. Контейнеру модального окна пишем соответствующий id, в нашем примере 'myModal1', а так же добавляем класс *modal*
4. В JS получаем не одну кнопку, а все с помощью `document.getElementsByClassName("myBtn")`
5. Изменяем обработчик нажатия на кнопку:

   ```js
   function buttonClick(event) {
     var id = this.getAttribute('data-modal');
      var modal = document.getElementById(id);
      modal.style.display = 'block';
   }
   for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
       btn[i].onclick = buttonClick;
   }
   ```
6. Для кнопок закрытия так же добавляем атрибут `data-modal`. Значение должно соответствовать атрибуту id модального окна, которое мы будем закрывать.
7. Кнопки закрытия выбираем так же все, а не одну: `var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close");`
8. И обработчик нажатия на этот span изменяем, аналогично кнопке открытия:

   ```js
   function spanClick() {
       var id = this.getAttribute('data-modal');
       var modal = document.getElementById(id);
       modal.style.display = 'none';
   }

   for (var i = 0; i < span.length; i++) {
      span[i].onclick = spanClick;
   }
   ```
9. И последний блок тоже меняем для работы со всеми модалками:

```js
window.onclick = function(event) {
  var isModal = (' ' + event.target.className + ' ').indexOf(' modal ') > -1;
  if (isModal) {
    event.target.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dxh5kstq/1/ - не работает :(

Comment: @kiLLro, моя ошибка. Нужно было назначить onclick для каждого элемента массива (я не учел, что нативный JS отдает именно массивы): https://jsfiddle.net/oddhz43x/. Основной ответ тоже поправил.

Comment: дык все равно не работает) Даже на твоем jsfiddle

Comment: Прошу прощения, надо было перепроверить. Последние правки там не сохранились. Актуальная версия: https://jsfiddle.net/oddhz43x/1/

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает :)